# Aggregating data in a window in apache beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am receiving a stream of a complex and nested JSON object as my input to my pipeline.

My goal is to create small batches to feed off to another `pubsub` topic for processing downstream. I am struggling with the `beam.beam.GroupByKey()` function - from what I have read this is the correct method to try and aggregate.

A simplified example, the input events:

```
{ data:['a', 'b', 'c'], url: 'websiteA.com' }
{ data:['a', 'b', 'c'], url: 'websiteA.com' }
{ data:['a'], url: 'websiteB.com' }
```

I am trying to create the following:

```
{
'websiteA.com': {a:2, b:2, c:2},
'websiteB.com': {a:1},
}
```

My issue lies in trying to group on anything more that the simplest tuple throws a `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.

I could run this in two steps, but from my reading using `beam.GroupByKey()` is expensive and therefore should be minimised.

EDIT based on answer from @Cubez.

This is my combine function which seems to half work :(

```py
class MyCustomCombiner(beam.CombineFn):
  def create_accumulator(self):
    logging.info('accum_created') #Logs OK!
    return {}

  def add_input(self, counts, input):
    counts = {}
    for i in input:
      counts[i] = 1
    logging.info(counts) #Logs OK!
    return counts

  def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
    logging.info('accumcalled') #never logs anything
    c = collections.Counter()
    for d in accumulators:
      c.update(d)
    logging.info('accum: %s', accumulators) #never logs anything
    return dict(c)

  def extract_output(self, counts):
    logging.info('Counts2: %s', counts) #never logs anything
    return counts
```

It seems past `add_input` nothing is being called?

Adding pipeline code:

```py
with beam.Pipeline(argv=pipeline_args) as p:
    raw_loads_dict = (p 
      | 'ReadPubsubLoads' >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=PUBSUB_TOPIC_NAME).with_output_types(bytes)
      | 'JSONParse' >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
    )
    fixed_window_events = (raw_loads_dict
      | 'KeyOnUrl' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x['client_id'], x['events']))
      | '1MinWindow' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60))
      | 'CustomCombine' >> beam.CombinePerKey(MyCustomCombiner())
    )
    fixed_window_events | 'LogResults2' >> beam.ParDo(LogResults())
```

Comment: Hey there, can you please edit with your pipeline code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a perfect example of needed to use [combiners](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine). These are transforms that are used to aggregate or combine collections across multiple workers. As the doc says, CombineFns work by reading in your element (beam.CombineFn.add_input), merging multiple elements (beam.CombineFn.merge_accumulators), then finally outputting the final combined value (beam.CombineFn.extract_output). See the Python docs for the parent class [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.12.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html?highlight=combinefn#apache_beam.transforms.core.CombineFn).

For example, to create a combiner that outputs an average of a collection of numbers looks like this:

```
class AverageFn(beam.CombineFn):
  def create_accumulator(self):
    return (0.0, 0)

  def add_input(self, sum_count, input):
    (sum, count) = sum_count
    return sum + input, count + 1

  def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
    sums, counts = zip(*accumulators)
    return sum(sums), sum(counts)

  def extract_output(self, sum_count):
    (sum, count) = sum_count
    return sum / count if count else float('NaN')

pc = ...
average = pc | beam.CombineGlobally(AverageFn())
```

For your use case, I would suggest something like this:

```
values = [
          {'data':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'url': 'websiteA.com'},
          {'data':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'url': 'websiteA.com'},
          {'data':['a'], 'url': 'websiteB.com'}
]

# This counts the number of elements that are the same.
def combine(counts):
  # A counter is a dictionary from keys to the number of times it has
  # seen that particular key.
  c = collections.Counter()
  for d in counts:
    c.update(d)
  return dict(c)

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
  pc = (p
        # You should replace this step with reading data from your
        # source and transforming it to the proper format for below.
        | 'create' >> beam.Create(values)

        # This step transforms the dictionary to a tuple. For this
        # example it returns:
        # [ ('url': 'websiteA.com', 'data':['a', 'b', 'c']),
        #   ('url': 'websiteA.com', 'data':['a', 'b', 'c']),
        #   ('url': 'websiteB.com', 'data':['a'])]
        | 'url as key' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x['url'], x['data']))

        # This is the magic that combines all elements with the same
        # URL and outputs a count based on the keys in 'data'.
        # This returns the elements:
        # [ ('url': 'websiteA.com', {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}),
        #   ('url': 'websiteB.com', {'a': 1})]
        | 'combine' >> beam.CombinePerKey(combine))

  # Do something with pc
  new_pc = pc | ...
```

Comment: Hey @Cubez appreciate the help, but I am still getting a KeyError, it is so hard to debug. I am logging what arrives at `add_input` and it is missing the key. I thought you had made a typo, but you actually meant to place the CustomCombine inside the Map()? Which I now have tried but do not understand why that would be the way to go about it? New error `Refusing to treat string as iterable...` but the key is a string..

Comment: LATE EDIT: in the add_input do you not need to initialise `counts`?

Comment: Hey @dendog, I'm testing out my implementation now and I'll edit when I'm done. As an FYI, Apache Beam has a Jupyter kernel you can use for notebook development at https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/interactive/README.md, it's great and I'm using it to write a better answer for you.

Comment: Oh nice this is cool! So my issue is now I think fixed - what I do not understand still is when does the `CombinePerKey()` call `merge_accumulators`? When does it know the unbounded pc is ready for that?

Comment: This will be called whenever the window is closed. For example, if you have fixed windows of 5 seconds, it will do the merging every 5 seconds. For unbounded PCollections, you will have to manually set up these windows to inform the pipeline when it is ready to merge. See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing for more information.

Comment: Btw! I edited my answer and removed the use of the custom combiner class for brevity. You might need more complex logic, but the single function combiner I think is easier to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196392/discussion-between-dendog-and-cubez).

Comment: So why did this work with a simple function (`combine()`) instead of a subclass of `beam.CombineFn`? I have tried something similar in my own code but it isn't working properly, so I'm attempting to subclass `CombineFn` instead. This part of Beam doesn't seem to be sufficiently documented right now.